# How to Elaborate GPS - EXIF Data

Tags: php

I have to print latitude & longitude of a picture location. I'm stuck at getting them. Here's the code:

```
    $exif = exif_read_data($picture_link, 0, true);

    echo "Latitude REF: " .$exif['GPS']['GPSLatitudeRef']
        ."<br>Latitude: " .print_r($exif['GPS']['GPSLatitude']) .
        ."<br>Longitude REF: " .$exif['GPS']['GPSLongitudeRef']
        ."<br>Longitude: " .print_r($exif['GPS']['GPSLongitude']);
```

And here's what I get back:

```
Latitude REF: N
Latitude: Array ( [0] => 44/1 [1] => 29/1 [2] => 5581/100 ) 
Longitude REF: E
Longitude: Array ( [0] => 11/1 [1] => 5/1 [2] => 401/100 )
```

How can I elaborate this data? Is there a better way to build a GPS?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you receive fractions for the geographic location.

- The first fraction 44/1 == 44 are degrees.
- The second fraction 29/1
  == 29 are minutes.
- And the third fraction 5581/100 == 55.81 are seconds.
- So the coordinate would be 44° 29' 55.81" N

Depending on the required format of the coordinates (decimal degrees, degrees-minutes, degrees-minutes-seconds) you should be able to calculate the result.

A sample implementation to receive decimal degrees would be the following:

```
function getCoordinates($exif) : array
{
    // check, if EXIF contains GPS-data
    // return empty array, if no GPS-data is present
    if(!isset($exif['GPS']) || !isset($exif['GPS']['GPSLatitude'])) return array();

    $info = $exif['GPS'];

    $lat_degrees_fraction = explode('/', $info['GPSLatitude'][0]);
    $lat_minutes_fraction = explode('/', $info['GPSLatitude'][1]);
    $lat_seconds_fraction = explode('/', $info['GPSLatitude'][2]);
    $lng_degrees_fraction = explode('/', $info['GPSLongitude'][0]);
    $lng_minutes_fraction = explode('/', $info['GPSLongitude'][1]);
    $lng_seconds_fraction = explode('/', $info['GPSLongitude'][2]);

    $lat_degrees = floatval($lat_degrees_fraction[0]) / floatval($lat_degrees_fraction[1]);
    $lat_minutes = floatval($lat_minutes_fraction[0]) / floatval($lat_minutes_fraction[1]);
    $lat_seconds = floatval($lat_seconds_fraction[0]) / floatval($lat_seconds_fraction[1]);
    $lng_degrees = floatval($lng_degrees_fraction[0]) / floatval($lng_degrees_fraction[1]);
    $lng_minutes = floatval($lng_minutes_fraction[0]) / floatval($lng_minutes_fraction[1]);
    $lng_seconds = floatval($lng_seconds_fraction[0]) / floatval($lng_seconds_fraction[1]);

    $lat = floatval($lat_degrees+((($lat_minutes*60)+($lat_seconds))/3600));
    $lng = floatval($lng_degrees+((($lng_minutes*60)+($lng_seconds))/3600));

    return array($lat, $lng);
}
```